# Help With Java Sudoku Permuter Program using Two Dimensional Array?

Tags: java, arrays, sudoku

I have to create a program that displays the 9 rows of a sudoku as 9 9-digit numbers and then prompt the user to do one of 6 operations on the sudoku. Then we have to output the sudoku each time the user performs an operation. This is sort of a sample run of how it should go:

```
Welcome to Sudoku Permuter.

   C C C C C C C C C
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
R1 0 8 0 4 0 2 0 6 0
R2 0 3 4 0 0 0 9 1 0
R3 9 6 0 0 0 0 0 8 4
R4 0 0 0 2 1 6 0 0 0
R5 2 0 0 0 0 9 6 0 0
R6 0 1 0 3 5 7 0 0 8
R7 8 4 0 0 0 0 0 7 5
R8 0 2 6 0 0 0 1 3 0
R9 0 9 0 7 0 1 0 4 0

(0 denotes a blank)

Enter 1 to swap two rows in a panel
Enter 2 to swap two columns in a panel
Enter 3 to swap two row panels
Enter 4 to swap two column panels
Enter 5 to swap two numbers
Enter 0 to end:
```

Let's say the user enters 3 (to swap two row panels). This would come up:

```
Enter row panels (1-3) to swap: 3 1
```

It would swap row panels 1 and 3, and this would be the output:

```
   C C C C C C C C C
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
R1 8 4 0 0 0 0 0 7 5
R2 0 2 6 0 0 0 1 3 0
R3 0 9 0 7 0 1 0 4 0
R4 0 0 0 2 1 6 0 0 0
R5 2 0 0 0 0 9 6 0 0
R6 0 1 0 3 5 7 0 0 8
R7 0 8 0 4 0 2 0 6 0
R8 0 3 4 0 0 0 9 1 0
R9 9 6 0 0 0 0 0 8 4

Rows 1-3 have been switched with rows 7-9.
```

Let's say the user inputs 5. This comes up:

```
Enter two numbers: 2 8
```

The original sudoku is outputted again, except 2's and 8's are switched throughout.

```
   C C C C C C C C C
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
R1 0 2 0 4 0 8 0 6 0
R2 0 3 4 0 0 0 9 1 0
R3 9 6 0 0 0 0 0 2 4
R4 0 0 0 8 1 6 0 0 0
R5 8 0 0 0 0 9 6 0 0
R6 0 1 0 3 5 7 0 0 2
R7 2 4 0 0 0 0 0 7 5
R8 0 8 6 0 0 0 1 3 0
R9 0 9 0 7 0 1 0 4 0
```

If the user entered 1, something would come up saying

```
Enter two rows (1-9) to switch:
```

And whichever rows the user enters, those two individual rows would be swapped and the sudoku would once again be outputted. It'd be similar if the user entered 2, except 2 columns would be switched. Similarly, if the user entered 4, two column panels would be switched.

We're supposed to use a two dimensional array like this:

```
int [] [] sudoku = new int[10] [10]
```

I have no idea how to do this. I've been struggling all semester, this is my first programming class. I just don't understand arrays at all, and I don't understand how we're even supposed to display the sudoku in the first place. This problem isn't in our book, so I have nothing to look back on, either. I really need to pass this class. If anyone could help me, I really appreciate it. Try to make it easy to understand, there's a lot of stuff I haven't learned how to do yet (ex: for the record, idk what parseInt is). I've tried reading the book (several times). It helps some, but this program is going to be impossible. Thank you SO much for the help.

Comment: Try breaking up the problem into smaller chunks.  Focus on just getting the user input first, and then calling some methods to handle the input.  Break up each of the 6 menu options into a separate method, and just make method stubs that don't do anything to start with.  Once the input works well, then think about how to print out the grid.  Then maybe focus on implementing each of the options.  Ask specific questions in each of these areas as you try to work it out, instead of just pasting your homework.

Comment: And note that you probably have not received many answers because contributers will much rather answer a specific question that shows some effort on your part, rather than "I have no idea how to do this...I really need to pass this class."  What specific parts are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do you know how to read input?
2. Do you know how to work with 1-dimensional arrays (lists), like {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}?
3. Do you understand for loops?
4. What part of the concept of arrays seems difficult to you?

For instance, here's a block of code that just prints out the raw contents of the array.  Does this code make sense?

```
int [] [] sudoku = new int[10] [10];
// loop through all of the rows
for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    // loop through all columns for each row
    for (int column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
        // print out the sudoku value at that row and column
        System.out.print(sudoku[row] [column] + " ");
    }
    // at the end of the row, print a blank line to start the next row
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here's how you can hard-code your sample board to work with it:

```
int [] [] sudoku = new int [] [] {
    { 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0 },
    { 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 1, 0 },
    etc.
}
```

Here's some pseudo-code for swapping two rows.

```
Get first row # from user
Get second row # from user
Loop through each column in the board
    Swap(cell at first row #, current column, cell at second row #, current column)
End Loop
```

Swapping basically requires a temporary variable to hold one of the values while swapping:

```
Swap(a, b)
    Store a into Temp
    Store b into a
    Store Temp into b
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to read input. I wasn't trying to just put the homework up there, but I first just wanted some pseudocode to get me started so I don't do it completely wrong. I think I know how to work with 1 dimensional arrays, but I'm not sure. Yes, I understand for loops. I just don't understand the arrays at all...I feel like a complete idiot. Like, you have sudoku[row] [column] + " "

Comment: Why do you have the row and column in there? Why isn't it just blank brackets like [] []

Comment: I also don't understand how to put in the rows and columns. If I'm inputting the rows as 9 9-digit numbers, does that just mean type in system.out.println() and put a 9-digit number in the parenthesis and do that 9 times? Also, how am i supposed to identify the columns if the sudoku is put in as 9 rows?

Comment: Can I make an analogy to an Excel spreadsheet, maybe that will help?  Think of the sudoku array as a 10 row, 10 column spreadsheet.  We say int[][] sudoku because we're just defining the type to have two dimension (a grid (i.e., list of lists), instead of just a list).  When referencing a "cell" in the array, we need to specify which row and which column.  So what I'm doing is looping from 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 for the rows and columns, and then getting the contents of the cell at that row and column to print out on the screen, followed by a space (i.e, 0 8 5 4 4, etc. instead of 085444...)

Comment: Also try googling "Java multi-dimensional array."  There are many other explanations out there that might help to understand.  But the best thing might be to just copy / paste my code sample, and start playing with it, to try to understand what is going on.

Comment: actually, the analogy to the spreadsheet really helped. i think i'm starting to understand the array a little bit more. the one thing that really boggles me is does the array know that the first set of numbers you put in is a row? so the first block of code that prints the raw contents and the second block of code that hardcodes it are supposed to do the same thing right? just a different way of doing it? sorry that i keep asking questions. i know you probably think i'm stupid...

Comment: Thank you both so much. I tried to mark your answers as useful, but it wouldn't let me. You have no idea how much it helped!

Comment: @anonymous - Remember that the only thing Java knows about is an array.  There's no such thing as a "grid" in Java.  It's only an array of arrays.  There's also no such thing as a "row" or "column".  Those are arbitrary names we put on them to make sense of it ourselves.  It could just as easily have been sudoku [column] [row] as sudoku [row] [column].  We are storing an array of rows, where each row is itself another array containing the columns.  Put together, it has the same effect as a grid or spreadsheet or whatever analogy makes sense.

Comment: @anonymous - Glad to help.  Not everyone is as nice as I am.  Put forth some effort to work through the question and come back with specific answers, and you will surely get more help.  Also, look for resources at your university (such as tutoring), programming resources and tutorials online.  There are lots of resources out there, just spend some time working through it, and most importantly, trying it out with some actual code to see what happens. That's the best way to learn IMHO.  Theory and reading will only take you so far.

Comment: @anonymous - Click the up-arrow next to any post that was helpful to add a vote to it.  If you think one of the posts is a sufficient answer to your question, click the checkbox under the vote count to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mellamokb's comment says, breaking things down into parts is the trick. At first glance I would probably do something like this:

1. Hardcode in a sudoku board, and make a routine to print the board out
2. Once that works right, then you'd need a menu. So extend your program to make a little menu that prints back the user's selection, and does nothing more
3. Once that's going, you can start filling in the menu choices. So when the user selects option one, make the routine for swapping two rows. The other menu items can still just print out their number.

Once you've got that working, you're actually nearly done. You can take your routine from #3 and make copies of it with small changes to make other 4 modifications possible.

You don't mention where the sudoku board comes from. If it's hardcoded, you're done. If not, then all you have to is make that method. At this point, you already know that you can print the board right, show the menu, and change the board.

You mention problems with arrays, and they can be a bit of a leap. Is there a specific question you have about arrays that we might be able to help with? They are like anything else in programming. You start not knowing a ton about them, and just sort of following what guidance and code you find elsewhere. As you gain more experience (as you will on this project and future projects), they'll be less mysterious and make more sense until one day they're as easy as 3 + 7.

Comment: What do you mean by hardcoding and making a menu?

Comment: I know I didn't mention where the sudoku board comes from. I went online and found a random sudoku and put the numbers on there. The professor told us to input the sudoku as 9 9-digit numbers, but I don't think he meant to input it from the Scanner? That's one thing I'm struggling with. I understand the input from the Scanner...the main thing I'm struggling with is how to swap two things in the board. How can I do that? Does it involve the array?

Comment: @anonymous - see my example for how to hardcode a sudoku array

Comment: @anonymous - a menu is basically printing out the options in some sort of infinite loop, and then waiting for the user to input a value.  Check if the user typed 1, then call your swapTwoRows method, if the user typed 2, call your swapTwoColumns method, etc.  If the input is invalid, let the user know they need to type 0-5.  Once you process the input, then loop and display the board again along with the menu.  So like while(true) { displayBoard(); displayMenu(); getInputFromUser(); processInput(); }

Comment: @anonymous - think of how you would swap two rows in a spreadsheet, or on a grid on a piece of paper.  You would start at the top, take the number in the first row, copy it into the box in the second row.  Then take the number in the second row, copy it into the box for the first row.  So on and so forth through the entire row.  Same thing in Java, loop through the contents of the two rows, swapping each cell back and forth.  See my post for example of swapping pseudo-code if that helps.

Comment: I'm still having trouble with a few things. First, I know how to swap the rows, but since the sudoku was hard coded in, I don't know how to retrieve the numbers. I also have to print the sudoku before the user is prompted, but I don't know how. I tried to do System.out.println(sudoku), but random characters come up. I also don't know how to display the C1, C2, C3, etc. and the R1, R2, R3, etc. Any suggestions are appreciated! Here's my (probably terrible) code:

Comment: import java.util.Scanner; public class SudokuPermuter { public static void main(String[] args) { Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); System.out.println("Welcome to Sudoku Permuter.\n");

  int [] [] sudoku = { 
      { 0, 8, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0 }, 
      { 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 9, 1, 0 }, 
      { 9, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4 }, 
      { 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0 }, 
      { 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 6, 0, 0 }, 
      { 0, 1, 0, 3, 5, 7, 0, 0, 8 }, 
      { 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 5 }, 
      { 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0 }, 
      { 0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0 } 
    };

Comment: System.out.println(sudoku); 
  System.out.println();
  System.out.print("Enter 1 to swap two rows in a panel\n" + 
  "Enter 2 to swap two columns in a panel\n" + 
  "Enter 3 to swap two row panels\n" + 
  "Enter 4 to swap two column panels\n" + 
  "Enter 5 to swap two numbers\n" + 
  "Enter 0 to end: ");

Comment: int choice = input.nextInt(); 
  if (choice == 1) { 
      System.out.print("Enter 2 rows (1-9) to swap: "); 
      int r1 = input.nextInt(); 
      int r2 = input.nextInt(); 
    } 
  else if (choice == 2) { 
      System.out.print("Enter 2 columns (1-9) to swap: "); 
      int c1 = input.nextInt(); 
      int c2 = input.nextInt(); 
    }

Comment: else if (choice == 3) { 
      System.out.print("Enter 2 row panels (1-3) to swap: "); 
      int rp1 = input.nextInt(); 
      int rp2 = input.nextInt(); 
    }

Comment: else if (choice == 4) { 
      System.out.print("Enter 2 column panels (1-3) to swap: "); 
      int cp1 = input.nextInt(); 
      int cp2 = input.nextInt(); 
    } 
  else if (choice == 5) { 
      System.out.print("Enter 2 numbers (1-9) to swap: "); 
      int num1 = input.nextInt(); 
      int num2 = input.nextInt(); 
    } 
  else if (choice == 0) { 
      System.exit(0); 
    } 
  else { 
      System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again"); 
    } 
} 
}

Comment: @anonymous - You've got a good start on your menu!  Think about putting those in separate methods so your Main() doesn't turn into a big series of menu options and input.  Also, you can edit your first answer to put code in, which might look better, or make a new answer.